# Character match count between strings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string (say string 1) that needs to be matched to another string (string2). Both the strings will have the same length and are case in-sensitive.

I want to print the number of character matches between both the strings.

```
E.g.: String 1: stranger
      String 2: strangem

      Match count = 7
```

I tried this:

```
$string1 = "stranger";
$string2 = "strangem";
my $count = $string1 =~ m/string2/ig;

print "$count\n";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want 0 or 2 for `aabb` and `bbcc`?

Comment: and, if 0, do you want 1 or 2 for abc and azc?

Comment: Hi Ikegami, it should be 0.

Comment: Hi ysth, it should be 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclusive or, then count the null characters (where the strings were the same):

```
my $string1 = "stranger";
my $string2 = "strangem";
my $count = ( lc $string1 ^ lc $string2 ) =~ tr/\0//;

print "$count\n";
```

I missed the "case in-sensitive" bit.

Comment: Above code is working fine. Can you please provide what does "^" and tr/\0// represents?

Comment: `^` is the [exclusive or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or), here used in its [string mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators). it will produce a string that has \0 wherever the two input strings had the same character.  `tr` is the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2FSEARCHLIST%2FREPLACEMENTLIST%2Fcdsr), here used just to count characters.

Comment: Don't you need the `c` modifier?  eg. `tr/\0//c`

Comment: @CJ7 that would count non-matches, the question asks for a count of matches

Answer (score 3):

You can use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string1=lc('stranger');
my $string2=lc('strangem');
my $count=0;
for (0..length($string1)-1) {
    $count++ if substr($string1,$_,1) eq substr($string2,$_,1);
}
print $count; #prints 7
```

Or you can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to get all characters as an array, and loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string1=lc('stranger');
my $string2=lc('strangem');
my $count=0;
my @chars1=split//,$string1; 
my @chars2=split//,$string2;
for (0..$#chars1) {
    $count++ if $chars1[$_] eq $chars2[$_];
}
print $count; #prints 7
```

(`fc` gives more accurate results than `lc`, but I went for backwards compatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
sub cm
{
    my @a = shift;
    my @b = shift;

    # First match prefix of string:
    my $n = 0;
    while ($n < $#a && $n < $#b && $a[$n] eq $b[$n]) {
       ++$n;
    }
    # Then skip one char on either side, and recurse.
    if ($n < $#a && $n < $#b) {
       # Match rest by skipping one place:
       my $n2best = 0;
       my $n2a = cm(splice(@a, $n), splice(@b, $n + 1));
       $n2best = $n2a;
       my $n2b = cm(splice(@a, $n + 1), splice(@b, $n));
       $n2best = $n2b if $n2b > $n2best;
       my $n2c = cm(splice(@a, $n + 1), splice(@b, $n + 1));
       $n2best = $n2c if $n2c > $n2best;
       $n += $n2best;
    }
    return $n;
}

sub count_matches
{
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;

    my @a_chars = split //, $a;
    my @b_chars = split //, $b;
    return cm(@a_chars, @b_chars); 
}

print count_matches('stranger', 'strangem')
```