# How can I count character matches in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, matching

Eg:

```
String 1: Can We Live (feat. Cece Rogers) [Joke Instrumental Mix] 
String 2: Can We Live (feat. Cece Rogers) Joke Instrumental Mix 

 Match count = 53
```

Have read this: [Character match count between strings in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794209/character-match-count-between-strings-in-perl)

Want to do this pythonically.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: you may want to look for Edit Distance between your strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572299/using-python-efficiently-to-calculate-hamming-distances ?

Comment: Did you realize that for the referenced question, match count is **not** 53 but **33** : the question refered to same characters **in same position** ?!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question asked in your heading, you can get a count of the number of matching characters in two strings with:

```
In [1]: s1 = 'Can We Live (feat. Cece Rogers) [Joke Instrumental Mix]'
In [2]: s2 = 'Can We Live (feat. Cece Rogers) Joke Instrumental Mix'

In [3]: if len(s1) > len(s2):     # swap strings so that s1 is shortest
   .....:     s1, s2 = s2, s1
   .....:     

In [4]: sum(c1==s2[i] for i, c1 in enumerate(s1))
Out[4]: 32
```

But this may not be a good enough measure of similarity for your purposes. Look into the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and its implementation in the [`distance` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance) instead if that is the case.

EDIT: @Veedrac is perfectly correct: a simpler, one-line solution without the swap is:

```
sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

(`zip` ignores items in the longer sequence).

Comment: Or just `sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))` without the swapping stuff. Heck, even just `sum(map(eq, s1, s2))` with `from operator import eq`.